# How to change the direction of an image in html?

Tags: html, css

I would like to know  what the HTML or CSS Code to set the direction of an image is.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "the direction of an image"? If you mean some specific graphics processing, such as mirroring, flipping or rotating then ask about that.

Comment: You want to add a wind effect?

Comment: We would need some code and or a more in depth explanation of what you are looking for. If you mean you would like to change the orientation, as in, a picture you need rotated to be a 180 flip, that is easily doable.

Answer (score 1):

**Your question is not cleared!** 
But, if you mean change the direction of an image in HTML by flipping! 
Then, 
**You can use this code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
}
</style>
</head>
<body

<img src="Image URl" height="auto" width="auto">

</body>
</html>
```

on this code when mouse is over image. then the image will be fliped!
If you don't want the Hover effect. then, simply remove it from the code.

```
img {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

***The image will be fliped! as you asked. Enjoy Coding!***